# Getting Fata signal 11 when trying to use Observable

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, rx-java2, android-room

I'm working on a project trying for the first time Kotlin, RxJava 2, and the new android architecture components. I'm trying to execute a delete method from Room on separate Thread and I'm getting `ERROR: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x0 in tid 12673 (RxCachedThreadS)` when executing the method, and the force closes. I'm trying these two options:

1.

```
Single.fromCallable { deviceViewModel.delete(device.phone) }
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe()
```

2.

```
Observable.just(Unit)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .map { deviceViewModel.delete(device.phone) }
            .subscribe()
```

Here's my DeviceViewModel.kt (using AndroidViewModel)

```
class DeviceViewModel constructor(application: Application) : AndroidViewModel(application) {

@Inject lateinit var db: AppDatabase

init {
    (application as KaiApplication).appComponent.inject(this)
}

fun count() = db.deviceModel().count();

fun getDevices() = db.deviceModel().devices();

fun getDevice(phone: String) = db.deviceModel().device(phone)

fun create(device: Device): Device {
    db.deviceModel().createOrUpdate(device).let {
        return device
    }
}

fun createTestDevice(name: String, phone: String) {
    db.deviceModel().createTestDevice(name, phone)
}

fun delete(device: Device): Device {
    db.deviceModel().delete(device).let {
        return device
    }
}

fun delete(devicePhone: String) {
    db.deviceModel().delete(devicePhone)
}
```

And my DeviceDao.kt

```
@Dao
abstract class DeviceDao {

    @Query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM device")
    abstract fun count(): Int

    @Query("SELECT * FROM device")
    abstract fun devices(): Flowable<List<Device>>

    @Query("SELECT * FROM device WHERE phone = :p0")
    abstract fun device(phone: String): Device?

    fun createOrUpdate(device: Device) {
        Timber.d("Device to create $device")
        insertOrUpdate(device)
    }

    fun createTestDevice(name: String, phone: String) {
        val device: Device = Device()
        device.phone = phone
        device.name = name
        device.password = "12345"

        Timber.d("Device to create $device")
        insertOrUpdate(device)
    }

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    abstract fun insertOrUpdate(vararg devices: Device)

    @Query("DELETE FROM device WHERE phone = :p0")
    abstract fun delete(phone: String)

    @Delete
    abstract fun delete(device: Device)
```

I've tried to solve this, but no success. Any help would come in hand. Thanks!

Comment: Signal 11 is SIGSEGV, segmentation fault. Are you sure your native libraries are OK?

Comment: @TassosBassoukos could you be more specific? I can show you my build.gradle if needed

Comment: Signal 11 usually means that your process tried to access something outside its address space, or tried writing in a protected memory area. This should not be possible from within Java/Dalvik/ART, as they're explicitly designed to be safe. The most probable cause is that you are using the NDK to develop native libs and there's a bug there.

Comment: @TassosBassoukos I don't think I'm using anything of the NDK. But thanks for the explanation

Comment: I also just got it: `Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x0 in tid 29799 (RxCachedThreadS)` using RxJava 2.1.2, RxAndroid 2.0.1, kotlin_version = '1.1.51'

Comment: Did you found a solution for this?

Comment: @AndroidRuntimeException Yes I think. Turns out I was missing the foreign relationship between 2 tables, is what I can remember.

Comment: @JosueMavarez The strange is, I am not using realm or a database.

Comment: @AndroidRuntimeException I don't remember that much when I encounter this issue, but I'll check the project's repository.

Answer (score 1):

I had prettyy much the same problem. My scenario was this: I had a `RecyclerView` list, and each item in the list had a delete button. The delete button fired off an `Observable` which deleted the item from the Room table. At the same time, the table of items was being observed by another `Observable` which was updating the `RecyclerView` which was using a `PagedList` adapter.

The OP hinted that this might be the problem in comments, just wanted to confirm: after converting my code to use LiveData instead of RxJava, I got a proper error message, which was a `FOREIGN KEY CONSTRAINT` failure when deleting the item (in my case, I had another entity which was linked to the entity being deleted, and I had `onDelete` set to `RESTRICT`).

For some reason, this particular error causes RxJava to absolutely freak out, instead of returning an error message. Seems like a bug.